# AJAX in fullcalendar function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

How can I add a ajax call into my `viewRender`?

For example:

```
var currentMonth = moment().month();

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    viewRender: function(view, element){
        url: '/getevents.php',
        type: 'POST', // ERROR LINE
        fail: function() {
            alert('There was an error while fetching events.');
        }
    }

});
```

the error I get is this:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

how can i fix this?

Comment: `url: '/getevents.php,` missing `'`

Comment: Can you see the color change after not adding " ' " after '/getevents.php?

Comment: No sorry I had it there, just made a mistake when copying and pasting. still getting the error....

Comment: Where are you sending the data?

Comment: You see unexpected token because you're using a wrong syntax. You're declaring object properties inside a function not an object

Comment: I edited the op. @Gerardo ok how do I go about fixing this? sorry im new to javascript

Comment: @JasonBale Are you using jQuery?

Comment: @Gerardo yes i am

Comment: @JasonBale Change it the code to this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geradrum/j0s6rkx3/)

Comment: @Gerardo it's working! :) post an answer and i will accept.

Comment: @JasonBale Sure, anything else tag me in a comment.

Comment: @gerardo ok. i have a question. i added `success: function (data) { console.log(data); },` and `data` is my json. how can i add the json events into my calendar?

Comment: @JasonBale I'm not familiar with fullcalendar I only used it once and like a year ago. But maybe this will help you [Fullcalendar render event when view is change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26626509/fullcalendar-render-event-when-view-is-change)

Comment: @Gerardo ok thank so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution:

First you need to make an AJAX call and since you're using jQuery, use `$.ajax()`

```
var currentMonth = moment().month();

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    viewRender: function(view, element){
      $.ajax({
        url: '/getevents.php',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
          // SUCCESS CODE
        },
        // ERROR LINE
        error: function() {
          alert('There was an error while fetching events.');
        }
      });
    }

});
```

And about the error, that's because it is what it says. You're defining object properties inside a function with the wrong syntax.